# How to update your django page by looking for new data in the db?

Tags: python, django, chart.js

I try to create a dashboard using django and chart.js.

My modul looks like:

```
class Sets(models.Model):

   time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   set1 = models.IntegerField()
   set2 = models.IntegerField()
   set3 = models.IntegerField()
```

my views:

```
from .function_sum import get_sets
from .models import Sets
def home(request, *args, **kwargs):
   sets = Sets.objects.all()
   time = []
   set1 = []
   set2 = []
   set3 = []

   time, set1, set2, set3= get_sets()

   data = {
       "sets" : sets,
       "time": time,
       "set1": set1,
       "set2": set2,
       "set3": set3
   }

   return render(request, "pages/home.html", data)

class ChartData(APIView):
   authentication_classes = []
   permission_classes = []
   sets = Sets.objects.all()
   time = []
   set1 = []
   set2 = []
   set3 = []

   time, set1 , set2 , set3 = get_sets()


   def get(self, request, format=None):

      data = {
        "time": self.time,
        "set1": self.set1,
        "set2": self.set2,
        "set3": self.set3
       }

       return Response(data)
```

get_sets is getting the current data from my Set datatable.

my html file which is included in layout page:

```
<div class="col-xl-6" url-endpoint='{% url "chart-data" %}'>
    <div class="card mb-5">
        <div class="card-header"><i class="fas fa-chart-line mr-1"></i>Chart</div>
        <div class="card-body"><canvas id="SetChart" width="100%" height="40"></canvas></div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
var endpoint ='chart/data'
var labels = []
var set1 = []
var set2 = []
var set3 = []






$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.time
        set1 = data.set1
        set2 = data.set2
        set3 = data.set3


        var ctx = document.getElementById('SetChart').getContext('2d');
        var startingData = {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: '1',
                    data: set1,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                    pointStyle : "point",
                    borderWidth: 1
                },{
                    label: '2',
                    data: set2,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(20, 0, 0, 1)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                    
                    borderWidth: 1
                },{
                    label: '3',
                    data: set3,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 99, 132, 1)',
                    fill: false,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            }

        var SetChart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'line', data: startingData, options:{}});
        

    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    },
}),

setInterval(function(){

   SetChart.data.labels= data.time
   SetChart.data.datasets[0].data = data.set1
   SetChart.data.datasets[1].data = data.set2
   SetChart.data.datasets[2].data = data.set3

   SetChart.update();
}, 1000);

</script>
```

I'm pretty new to django, js, html, chart.js and even python so almost all I did I've just copied and modified from tutorials.

My chart gets displayed with the current database data and labels of the moment I run my django server with py manage.py runserver.
But while I run a generator in the background, writing random values into my Set table the chart is not even updating when I press F5. Only if I stop the server and run it again.

How can I let my chart check for new data in my db and update every few minutes (better immediately after db was updated)
Also I couldn't handle pop and push functions. Actually my chart only should show the last 10 datas and labels of my db.

### Update

Based on the command I just made it work.

I updated my html and included following into my $.ajax call after var SetChart:

```
        function addLabel(chart,label){
            chart.data.labels.push(label)
            chart.update();
        }

        function addData(chart, data, index) {
            chart.data.datasets[index].data.push(data)
            chart.update();
        }

        function removeData(chart) {
            try{
                chart.data.labels.shift();
                chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
                    dataset.data.shift();
                });
                chart.update();
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log(e)

            }
        }

        function updateChart(chart, label, set1, set2, set3){
            addLabel(chart,label)
            addData(chart, set1.slice(-1)[0], 0)
            addData(chart, set2.slice(-1)[0], 1)
            addData(chart, set3.slice(-1)[0], 2)
            removeData(chart);
        }

        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: endpoint,
                success: function(data){
                    labels = data.time
                    set1 = data.set1
                    set2= data.set2
                    set3= data.set3
                    updateChart(SetChart, labels.slice(-1)[0], set1, set2, set3) 
                    SetChart.update();
                },
                error: function(error_data){
                    console.log("error")
                    console.log(error_data)
                }
            })
        }, 60000);
```

And removed the other setIntervall function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your input, I guess first request is calling `home` view and loads initial set data - which is then displayed on html page. On the other hand, then you are using `ChartData` API view. If this scenario is right - then:

The problem in `ChartData` is that, this part `time, set1 , set2 , set3 = get_sets()` is executed one time when django is initialized (as described). What you need is to get sets each time when request is sent. And the code fragment is executing upon request is in `get` method.

Right solution would look like this:

```
class ChartData(APIView):
   authentication_classes = []
   permission_classes = []
   sets = Sets.objects.all()

   def get(self, request, format=None):
      time, set1 , set2 , set3 = get_sets()

      data = {
        "time": time,
        "set1": set1,
        "set2": set2,
        "set3": set3
       }

       return Response(data)
```

There is no need for extra class variables (`self.set1` ...). And the `get_sets` function is called each time request reaches the `get` method.

**Update (based on comment)**

To avoid loading whole data each time request is handled by API View - I would keep track of last record received in frontend and based on last record id (there may be another field) I would fetch records created after the id you're tracking in frontend.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the first problem.
I use the ChartData API view just to get JSON data. I know that's certainly not the common way but it worked.
Do you have a solution for the updating chart with pop and push data?

Comment: have you meant it like the updated section of the question?